# Installing Pillow on macOS Mojave - running python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I'm totally new and all the stuff within Terminal is beyond me.

I mananged to get Pillow 5.3 installed on my computer, but it went into the Python 2.7 folder in Library. I've been using Python 3.7 in PyCharm as I learn.

None of the import commands are working:

```
import PIL
from PIL import pillow
import pillow
```

My system doesn't recognize any of these. Do I need to move the Pillow 5.3 folder somewhere? I must be missing a step somewhere.

Comment: What command did you use to install Pillow in the first place?

Comment: Try `from PIL import Image`

Comment: @johnpaton I used pip install pillow, which was apparently the problem! A commenter below said i needed to use 

    pip3 install pillow

which I did, however, i got a syntax error in Terminal

EDIT: It worked. Let's see if I can get this going. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to install `pillow` for Python 3.7, not 2.7.

```
pip3 install pillow
```

(if `pip3` is available from your command line, otherwise, look where PyCharm has its Python 3.7 install).

Comment: I used pip3 install pillow and it seemed to work. Asking me now to upgrade pip version 10.0.1 to 18.1. Do I need that?

Also, still not sure if pycharm is recognizing my import commands. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Make sure you are using the right python and not python 2. updating pip is not a bad idea, but not mandatory now that you have the packages you needed.

Comment: PyCharm says Python 3.7 is project interpreter, which is good. Pillow is listed as a package in those settings as well, but I still can't seem to import it properly.

Comment: actually from PIL import Image worked for me. I think i'm up and running. Thank you for the tips.

Comment: Enjoy playing with pillow!